# Fedora 29 -- 500gb Hard Drive only storing 52.6gb

Tags: fedora, partition, hard-disk, storage, gparted

I have two hard drives on my laptop. One has 1tb with windows 10 and the other is 500gb (which I took from an old laptop) with fedora 29. When I went into the disk usage analyzer (DUA) on Fedora 29 I noticed that it said I had 40.7gb/52.6gb available ,despite the fact the hard drive was 500gb. I booted into Windows to format the hard drive and made sure that the drive was formatted properly. After that, I then reinstalled the Fedora 29 on to the 500gb hard drive. After I reinstalled the operating system, the DUA still said it had 52.6gb. What was even more weird was that when I went into gParted to check the drive partitions, the partition with the lvm2 file system (which is 464.57 Gib) was all yellowed out. Is there a way that I can store a reasonable amount of space on the 500gb hard drive with Fedora?[image]

I formatted the drive and it says that the free space is 465gb also I'm not too sure which number is the model so here is a photo of the hard drive. I think it is WWN:5000C50045A401A8 but I'm not too sure. I also checked to see if the Hard Drive had any bad sectors with Defraggler and the program said that the disk is in good health.[image]

Comment: 1) What is the make and model of the repurposed drive? 2) Please go back into Windows, run `diskpart` from an Elevated Command Prompt window, and _clean_ the drive, then repartition and reformat it w/ NTFS. 3) What does Windows say its capacity is? Please click [edit] and update the question with that data. If you have a SMART disk tool, please also check for bad sectors and other problems.

Comment: @K7AAY  I formatted the disk and it said it had 465gb. I also got the model number which i think is WWN:5000C50045A401A8 but I'm not sure so I took a picture of the drive and edited my post like you told me.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the output of

```
pvs
lvs
vgs
pvdisplay
lvdisplay
vgdisplay
```

You will see where your ~450 GB is.

Depending on the output of the above you can then resize with something like

```
lvextend -L 100% /dev/vg/root
```

Comment: Can you clarify this?

Comment: @pedro the likely issue is that the / partition is an LVM, and 50gb in size. As the answer noted, if you loo, at the lvdisplay you will probably see available space.

Comment: @KevinO Is there a way to resize the partition?

Comment: @PedroMalavet, yes, you can resize the partition. In essence, use the commands as noted in the answer to find available space. You then use `lvresize` to adjust the particular size of an LVM, or you can add another LVM. There are many questions/answers on this site on the particular process. if you wish to ask a new question about your specific case, be sure to provide the information from `vgs` and `lvs`.

Answer (score 0):

Your HDD really is an eight year old 465GB [Seagate ST9500325AS](https://www.seagate.com/staticfiles/support/disc/manuals/notebook/momentus/5400.6%20(Wyatt)/100528359e.pdf) which runs at a pokey 5400RPM. It's also inefficiently partitioned:

[image: Use of space]

sdb1 only uses 18MB, and giving it 200MB is overkill. Next time, I'd give sdb1 only about 50MB.

sdb2 uses 246MB and has 754 MB free.

sdb3 is partitioned with lvm. I suggest you run [vgdisplay](http://landoflinux.com/linux_lvm_command_examples.html) to see how its space is used.

And, since an eight year old consumer HDD is a failure waiting to happen, I would suggest you replace it; a much faster and very well respected SSD is only [$78 at Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0781Z7Y3S). You will also get longer battery life as well as faster Linux response time.